# leaflet multiple markers django map reference?

Tags: javascript, python, django, leaflet

I'm using Python 3.4, latest Django with the leaflet django install.  I'm able to display the map, and add 1 marker from my list.

The problem is adding all of the markers in the list.  The code renders all of the markers but not all of them get added to the map.  Maybe I'm losing the map reference via a scope issue?  I'm not sure.  Here is my code, I really could use the help.

```js
{% load leaflet_tags %}

<head>
    
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
</head>

<body>


{% if latest_device_list %}
 <script type="text/javascript">

    {% for device in latest_device_list %}
    function map_init_basic (map, options) {
  
        marker = new L.marker([{{device.Device_Lat}}, {{device.Device_Lon}}])
  .bindPopup("<h3>"+{{device.Device_IMEI}}+"</h3>")
  .addTo(map);  
  
              }
    {% endfor %}
 </script>
{% else %}
    <p>No Devices are available.</p>
{% endif %}
  {% leaflet_map "yourmap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}   
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really unfamiliar with django, so i could be wrong but doesn't your `for` loop insert multiple `map_init_basic` methods/callbacks? So you declaring the same callback function over and over? And only one will execute on map initialization. My guess is that you should put the `for` loop in the callback function around the marker declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function map_init_basic (map, options) {

        {% for device in latest_device_list %}

            marker = new L.marker([{{device.Device_Lat}}, {{device.Device_Lon}}])
                .bindPopup("<h3>"+{{device.Device_IMEI}}+"</h3>")
                .addTo(map);  

        {% endfor %}

    }

</script>
```

What's happening now is that when you have say three markers in your device list, it would end up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function map_init_basic (map, options) {
        marker = new L.marker([0, 0])
            .bindPopup("<h3>"+ 'ABC' +"</h3>")
            .addTo(map);  
    }
    function map_init_basic (map, options) {
        marker = new L.marker([1, 1])
            .bindPopup("<h3>"+ 'DEF' +"</h3>")
            .addTo(map);  
    }
    function map_init_basic (map, options) {
        marker = new L.marker([2, 2])
            .bindPopup("<h3>"+ 'GHI' +"</h3>")
            .addTo(map);  
    }

</script>
```

The second function declaration, will overwrite the first, and the third will overwrite the second. So when `map_init_basic` gets called only the third function will execute.

Comment: When I move the for loop then none of the markers show up.

Comment: Ok, then i'm at a loss. One thing i can say, is that having multiple callback functions, makes completely no sense.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it's fixed, i'de just added some extra info, but ok, might come in handy for other users

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```js
{% if latest_device_list %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function map_init_basic (map, options) {
   var marker = null;
   map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    {% for device in latest_device_list %}
        marker = new L.marker([{{device.Device_Lat}}, {{device.Device_Lon}}])
  .bindPopup("<h3>"+{{device.Device_IMEI}}+"</h3>")
  .addTo(map);  
    {% endfor %}
  }
 </script>
{% else %}
    <p>No Devices are available.</p>
{% endif %}
  {% leaflet_map "yourmap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}   
</body>
```